# Changing the height of a Xamarin Forms NavigationPage Toolbar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the height of a Xamarin Forms Toolbar that is being rendered on Android with AppCompat. There is no height property from Forms to set this so I've attempted setting the `layout_height` in the `toolbar.axml` as follows

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
```

This doesn't change the height.

I've also tried setting

- android:minHeight
- android:height
- height
- android:actionBarSize

but those do not change the height either.

FWIW, when using Xamarin Forms non-AppCompat NavigationPage with the ActionBar, I was able to set the height with `android:height`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the below really helpful for the same issue.

[Xamarin Forms: How to change Toolbar height in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767775/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-toolbar-height-in-android)

- Add `<item name="android:actionBarSize">250dp</item>` into your styles.xml
- Remove `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` from Toolbar.axml.

This should let you define any height you want for your navigation bar.

Hope that helps

Comment: Seems to work well on Lollipop, but was ignored on KitKat.